# Disable onSceneTouch when pressing the Sprite button

Tags: android, touch, sprite, andengine, scene

I have a sprite as a button on the scene and i integrate AnalogScreenController,

I have actions onSceneTouch, onAreaTouch(Sprite mySprite) and onAnalogScreenControllerTouch.

When i press on the analogScrennController everything is ok, but when i try to touch the Sprite both onSceneAreaTouch and onAreaTouch(Sprite mySprite) is performed, but i want to disable sceneTouch when i press on my sprite (like in onAnalogScreenController).
I want to hide sprite when i press on the scene, but if i do so i can't press on my sprite, because if i try to touch it it dissapear before perform onAreTouch acntion.

Comment: I understand that (1) When sprite is touched,  onSceneTouched is not triggered. But I do not understand what you are asking for (2) When scene is touch, hide the sprite. How do you want your sprite to reappear after disappearing when onSceneTouch is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean than when i touch my sprite i don't want to onSceneTouch actions to perform.

wrong code:

```
    mySprite = new Sprite(...){

    @Override
    boolean onAreaTouch(...){
    if (isActionUp){
    ...
    }
    return false;
    }
```

right code:

wrong code:

```
    mySprite = new Sprite(...){

    @Override
    boolean onAreaTouch(...){
    ...
    return true;
    }
```

In second version when i touch mySprite onSceneTouch() is no performed.